# select option in django didn't displayed the right data

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, django-models, django-templates

Can anyone help me with this issues. Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my program

template.html

```
<tbody>
{% for condition in conditioner %}
{{ condition.owner }}
{% with "#CCE6FF" as bgcolor %} 
<tr>
    <td style="height: 30">{{ condition.NEW_DATE }}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="SMOKER select_input" name="condition">
            <option value="{{condition.SMOKER.01}}" >Never</option>
            <option value="{{condition.SMOKER.02}}" >Ex-Smoker</option>
        </select>
    <td><input type="text" name="condition" id="condition{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ condition.WEIGHT }}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="condition" id="condition{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ condition.HEIGHT }}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="condition" id="condition{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ condition.BP }}" /></td>
</tr>
----more program---
```

models.py

```
class Condition(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(Afdeling)
CPR = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
NEW_DATE = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)

smoker = (("01" , 'Never'),
         ("02" , 'Ex-Smoker'),

SMOKER      = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = smoker, null = True, blank = True)    

WEIGHT      = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 1, null = True, blank = True)

HEIGHT      = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 1, null = True, blank = True)

BP = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length = 3, null = True, blank = True)
----more models.py---
```

[image: Condition output]

It shows the table and selected option but it's not showing the correct data.

> In my database 19 okt should be Ex-Smoker but here it shown Never to all of the column.

The html for the table are:

```
<select class="SMOKER select_input" name="condition">
<option value="2" >Never</option>
<option value >Ex-Smoker</option>
</select>
```

I hope my explanation is understandable and if anyone need more clarification I will try my best to explain. I really need help on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: your html is missing the "selected" string in options. you would have to render that. you should read about djangos integrated forms which will save you some hassle...

Comment: I agree with Jingo and jpic -- you are doing some non-standard things that probably make life harder. Just adding a couple links to [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) and the associated [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: thks for the comments and answer @Jingo

Comment: thks for the answer @dokkaebi..i will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit that I don't fully understand, for example what you're trying to do with `{{condition.SMOKER.01}}`, it looks like you would rather want to do `{{ condition.smoker.0.0 }}` and `{{ condition.smoker.1.0 }}` which would respectively output `01` and `02`, like in python `condition.smoker[0][0]` and `condition.smoker[0][1]`.

Anyway, about this:

> In my database 19 okt should be Ex-Smoker but here it shown Never to all of the column.

It is simply because you never set a option with `selected="selected"`. Maybe it should look like this:

```
    <select class="SMOKER select_input" name="condition">
        <option value="{{condition.smoker.0.0}}" {% if condition.SMOKER == condition.smoker.0.0 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>Never</option>
        <option value="{{condition.smoker.1.0}}" {% if condition.SMOKER == condition.smoker.1.0 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>Ex-Smoker</option>
    </select>
```

Hope this helps. But as I said, it is hard to understand what you are trying to do and the fact that you have deliberately broken common standards doesn't help: using caps for property names and lower case for pseudo-constants is the opposite of what we use to do - and what you can see in django documentation which would look like:

```
class Condition(models.Model):
    SMOKER_CHOICES = (
        ("01" , 'Never'),
        ("02" , 'Ex-Smoker'),
    )
    smoker = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SMOKER_CHOICES)
    # etc ....
```

So maybe you're just confused by your own makings ?

Comment: hi @jpic. thks for the answer.

Comment: You are right maybe i just confused by my own makings. I got the answer I am missing the `selected="selected"`. once again thanks a million:)

Comment: "The computing scientist’s main challenge is not to get confused by the complexities of his own making." — E. W. Dijkstra